# Logout as a user never take the user back to their login only in Lightning experience

Tags: login

I am system administrator. I used to login as another user and from there I switched to partner community app. When I am doing this, I used to duplicate the tab in Google Chrome so that to avoid messing up things. Now, when I tried to logout by clicking "Logout as xxxxxxxxx" and navigate back to my home page, it never logout but stayed on the same user login again and again. Any thoughts of why this is happening? Are there anyone experiencing similar kind of issues? I never have this issue when I am in classic. This is pertaining to Lightning Experience.

Comment: Duplicating the tab is likely the issue because of how the Lightning Experience works. To confirm, though, you might want to log a case with Support.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I will create a case with Salesforce support.